Jetpack Compose or XML, which is better for creating a large application with very many features, and complex features
I'm new android developer and i complete all the fundamentals and foundation of the android development with Kotlin, Now i look at build app like Instagram or Facebook or very complex app with complex features to improve my experience, So i want advice from the senior developer, which the best choice for app like instagram, Jetpack Compose or XML
I search on the YouTube and Google, but there is no one answer my question

They both will work well for large projects, the more important part is to use a proper architecture and cleanly structure and modularize the code.

StackOverflow discourages questions about selection of technologies or application architecture as "opinion-based". In truth, it's possible to make objective choices that are not opinion based - but not when presented with a single-paragraph statement of requirements. If I were consulting to your project I would want to spend several days studying the project requirements and constraints before offering advice.

I worked with Compose and XML for the same kind of projects. The big difference is Compose is more fluent after getting to know the syntax better.
I recommend working with Jetpack Compose because no matter the size of your application, it can be much more readable and clean. I will write the main points for both of them down below.
For XML :

Managing complex codes with XML usually requires more effort and may require additional libraries (LiveData, ViewModel, etc.).
Rendering is slow (not that slow, but as a user, you can see the difference).
Works fine with older versions of Android devices. If you want to reach a crowded user base, ensure that you research Android version usage.
You will separate the UI definitions from business logic. For me, it is hard to manage.

For Jetpack Compose :

You write the ui codes as Kotlin files within the business logic so they are easy to read and manage.
New tech, so not very good with older devices.
If you don't know Jetpack Compose, it is not a good idea to start learning with a big project. First, it can seem too much mess, but after getting used to it, it will be so much faster than XML.
Google supports Jetpack Compose and is continuously improving the technology. For new projects, it is highly recommended to go with Jetpack Compose.

